# validation on a repeated control firing for each control uniquely

Tags: asp.net, validation

My problem is this: I need to have a way to repeat a custom textbox control with validators and have each validator fire for each control uniquely (as opposed to one text box failing validation and the validators fire for all other controls also using that validator).

My idea was maybe to set the control to validate property uniquely for the full client ID of each?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Did it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've associated a custom javascript function to the text box blur.  It uses jquery to nab the validator controls nearest to the sender (and only those nearest).  I loop through them and call ValidatorValidate.

In addition to my above problem, this also allows me to only show the validation error that makes sense at the time (i.e. on blur of text box i don't want to show required field immediately because it's truly not required till i take action elsewhere... so I determine this by the sender and hook into this method in other locations).

I also don't show multiple.  If its beyond my range specified, i only show that (as opposed to other custom validators i have that would otherwise fire).